# enforce implementation of an interface

Tags: javascript, oop, interface, duck-typing

I came across the article about duck typing: http://jscriptpatterns.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/javascript-interfaces.html?view=sidebar
And I start to wonder whether this approach is efficient.
In situations where I have a lot of objects with inheritance and interface relations, the ensureImplements() method will be called many times.
I am wonder if there is a better way to enforce implementation of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

> And I start to wonder whether this approach is efficient.

There are indeed two arguments against the approach the OP is referring to and wondering about.

Firstly, if one was able setting up a project on TypeScript supporting development environments, the techniques described in that article do not provide any real benefit, but - as already mentioned - introduce performance issues and boilerplate overhead.

So, as always, making use of them depends on what the projects goals are, what the technical setup is and how skilled the developers are.

Secondly, and this is rather a strong opinion, since I can't justify it within just a couple of lines, I always will argue that native JavaScript does not need the concept of interfaces, for ECMAScript-3 already has a natural predisposition for Role based composition concepts like Mixins and Traits - thus talking about bundled implementations of production ready behavior that in a very handy way enable code-reuse.

Making use of [*Flight Mixins*](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins) (*Angus Croll - May 2011*) or the many `extends` approaches that implement Mixins by stepwise copying properties from one object onto another, is much closer to practical daily coding.

But if it comes to the *»enforce implementation«* part of the OP's question within such a Mixin/Trait based composition environment one then was in need of a custom `Requiring` Mixin that, as a pure function based implementation, might look like the following stripped-down example code ...

http://jsfiddle.net/n8m7c3po/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem with extend is that I don't have any contract between the main object and the extend object. For example, A can extend B but in order to work, B has to have a property name imageId.  On the other hand, A also make use of imageId. So, where this imageId property should be? This is why I am looking for a contract. Any suggestion?

Comment: If I understand correctly You like to do something with `A` and `B` but only if `B` fulfills certain criteria(s). Depending on the complexity of the (Your) code or what it tries to be an abstraction of, You might not even need a meta programming approach for just checking for the existence of an objects properties/methods. Could you please provide code that exemplifies the original problem Your question then arises from.